# How can I group an array of objects by key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

Does anyone know of a way (lodash if possible too) to group an array of objects by an object key then create a new array of objects based on the grouping? For example, I have an array of car objects:

```
const cars = [
    {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'r8',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'rs5',
        'year': '2013'
    }, {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'mustang',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'fusion',
        'year': '2015'
    }, {
        'make': 'kia',
        'model': 'optima',
        'year': '2012'
    },
];
```

I want to make a new array of car objects that's grouped by `make`:

```
const cars = {
    'audi': [
        {
            'model': 'r8',
            'year': '2012'
        }, {
            'model': 'rs5',
            'year': '2013'
        },
    ],

    'ford': [
        {
            'model': 'mustang',
            'year': '2012'
        }, {
            'model': 'fusion',
            'year': '2015'
        }
    ],

    'kia': [
        {
            'model': 'optima',
            'year': '2012'
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 199, accepted):

[Timo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40774759/240490) is how I would do it. Simple `_.groupBy`, and allow some duplications in the objects in the grouped structure.

However the OP also asked for the duplicate `make` keys to be removed. If you wanted to go all the way:

```js
var grouped = _.mapValues(_.groupBy(cars, 'make'),
                          clist => clist.map(car => _.omit(car, 'make')));

console.log(grouped);
```

Yields:

```js
{ audi:
   [ { model: 'r8', year: '2012' },
     { model: 'rs5', year: '2013' } ],
  ford:
   [ { model: 'mustang', year: '2012' },
     { model: 'fusion', year: '2015' } ],
  kia: 
   [ { model: 'optima', year: '2012' } ] 
}
```

If you wanted to do this using Underscore.js, note that its version of `_.mapValues` is called `_.mapObject`.

Answer (score 557):

In plain Javascript, you could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an object

```js
var cars = [{ make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' }, { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }],
    result = cars.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.make] = r[a.make] || [];
        r[a.make].push(a);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**UPDATE 2023**

Now with [`Object.groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy). It takes an iterable and a function for grouping.

```js
var cars = [{ make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' }, { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }],
    result = Object.groupBy(cars, ({ make }) => make);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: how can i iterate `result` results?

Comment: you could take the entries with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and loop through the key/value pairs.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the `make` from data set once grouped? It's taking extra space.

Comment: yes, by [Rest in Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring).

Comment: What does r and a stand for?
Would it be correct to assume that r is the accumulator and a the currentValue?

Comment: The best answer as ever. Why are you passing Object.create(null)?

Comment: @kartik, it creates an empty object without prototypes.

Comment: If you remove prototypes, How will the object has access to object's prototypes method?

Comment: @kartik, there is no one used here.

Comment: What does this line of code do r[a.make] = r[a.make] || [];

Comment: @Sarah, it generates a new property `a.make` with an array if it does not exist (the value of not existing properties is `undefined`). if exist, it assign itself.

Comment: Why do you need this line Object.create(null)? I read your answer to kartik but I don t understand it.

Comment: @Alex, the reason is to prevent to have for example prototype functions like `toString` as property. for the most application you need not to worry about but you nee to know it, this is to show to use a really emypty object.

Comment: Have you a specific example when ` toString ` can be a property?

Comment: @Alex, please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068424/push-a-array-object-into-another-array-object-if-the-value-not-exists/38068553#38068553

Comment: Its shows following error 
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value"

Comment: @SakthiKarthik, sorry, i can not help. i have no idea of *Vue*.

Comment: @NinaScholz could you help out here by any chance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72301893/get-value-of-object-key-and-parent-javascript-and-create-a-new-object/72302136#72302136

Comment: may I know how to understand this r[a.make] = r[a.make] || []; ? seems like assiging boolean value

Comment: @NinaScholz May I know how Object Destructuring could remove the make field?

Comment: @AeLeung, ad 1: its a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR), not a [bitwise OR `|`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR). ad 2: yes with a [Rest in Object Destructuring `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) and mapping this object.

Comment: Is there a way to make this use the order of the items in the array? I have sorted my array of objects by year descending e.g 2023, 2022, 2021, but this code example returns them in ascending order.

Comment: @MrPablo, objects have a given order, for positive 32 bit integer its sorted and coming first, then by insertation order.

Comment: @NinaScholz How can I exclude `"make"` from the groupBy callback to avoid displaying `"make": ""` in the return result?

Comment: @PennyLiu, `Object.groupBy` does not change the data. for removing a certrain property in the result, you need to take another iteration. there, you could map new objects (kepp original data set) or itterate the values and delete unwanted property (mutating original data set).

Comment: @NinaScholz Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 153):

**You are looking for [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#groupBy).**

Removing the property you are grouping by from the objects should be trivial if required:

```js
const cars = [{
  'make': 'audi',
  'model': 'r8',
  'year': '2012'
}, {
  'make': 'audi',
  'model': 'rs5',
  'year': '2013'
}, {
  'make': 'ford',
  'model': 'mustang',
  'year': '2012'
}, {
  'make': 'ford',
  'model': 'fusion',
  'year': '2015'
}, {
  'make': 'kia',
  'model': 'optima',
  'year': '2012'
}];

const grouped = _.groupBy(cars, car => car.make);

console.log(grouped);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.2/lodash.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: And if you want it shorter still, `var grouped = _.groupBy(cars, 'make');` No need for a function at all, if the accessor is a simple property name.

Comment: What '_' stands for?

Comment: @AdrianGrzywaczewski it was the default convention for name-spacing 'lodash' or 'underscore'. Now that the librairies are modular it's no longer required ie. https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.groupby

Comment: And how can I interate in the result?

Comment: I believe that would be with Object.keys(grouped)

Answer (score 140):

There is absolutely no reason to download a 3rd party library to achieve this simple problem, like the above solutions suggest.

The one line version to group a `list` of objects by a certain `key` in es6:

```
const groupByKey = (list, key) => list.reduce((hash, obj) => ({...hash, [obj[key]]:( hash[obj[key]] || [] ).concat(obj)}), {})
```

The longer version that filters out the objects without the `key`:

```js
function groupByKey(array, key) {
   return array
     .reduce((hash, obj) => {
       if(obj[key] === undefined) return hash; 
       return Object.assign(hash, { [obj[key]]:( hash[obj[key]] || [] ).concat(obj)})
     }, {})
}


var cars = [{'make':'audi','model':'r8','year':'2012'},{'make':'audi','model':'rs5','year':'2013'},{'make':'ford','model':'mustang','year':'2012'},{'make':'ford','model':'fusion','year':'2015'},{'make':'kia','model':'optima','year':'2012'}];

console.log(groupByKey(cars, 'make'))
```

NOTE: It appear the original question asks how to group cars by make, but omit the make in each group. So the short answer, without 3rd party libraries, would look like this:

```js
var groupByKey = (list, key) => list.reduce((map, obj) => {
 const group = obj[key];
if(map.has(key)) {
  map.get(group).push(obj);
} else { 
  map.set(group, [obj])
}
return map
}, new Map())


 var cars = [{'make':'audi','model':'r8','year':'2012'},{'make':'audi','model':'rs5','year':'2013'},{'make':'ford','model':'mustang','year':'2012'},{'make':'ford','model':'fusion','year':'2015'},{'make':'kia','model':'optima','year':'2012'}];

console.log(...groupByKey(cars, 'make', {omitKey:true}))
```

Comment: this is definitely not es5

Comment: I liked both of your answers, but I see they both provide "make" field as a member of each "make" array. I've provided an answer based on yours where the delivered output matches the expected output. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeevan `reduce` has as its argument a callback and an initial value. the callback has two args, previous and current value. Here, previous value is called `hash`. Maybe someone can explain more about its use here. It seems that `reduce` here reduces the array by a property which is extracted.

Comment: To anyone considering using this, be careful. The code is not optimised for large datasets, if you have a large array you want to group by, you're going to run into problems. I had an array of 33000 items that took almost 30 seconds to group with this.

I'm pretty sure the problem is mainly in the use of `{...hash}` in the reducer, which creates lots of unused objects that waste space, leading to excessive memory use and garbage collection

Comment: This option has very bad performance characteristics (quadratic time) and isn’t particularly readable. It should literally never be used.

Answer (score 32):

Here is your very own `groupBy` function which is a generalization of the code from: https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Lodash-Underscore

```js
function groupBy(xs, f) {
  return xs.reduce((r, v, i, a, k = f(v)) => ((r[k] || (r[k] = [])).push(v), r), {});
}

const cars = [{ make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' }, { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }];

const result = groupBy(cars, (c) => c.make);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I love this answer due to the fact that you can use nested properties with it as well - very nice. I just changed it for Typescript and it was exactly what I was looking for  :)

Comment: shorter version: `groupBy=(x,f,r={})=>(x.forEach(v=>(r[f(v)]??=[]).push(v)),r)`

Answer (score 24):

Its also possible with a simple `for` loop:

```
 const result = {};

 for(const {make, model, year} of cars) {
   if(!result[make]) result[make] = [];
   result[make].push({ model, year });
 }
```

Comment: And probably faster as well, and simpler. I've expanded your snippet to be a bit more dynamic as I had a long list of fields from a db table I didn't want to type in. Also note you will need to replace const with let.

`for ( let { TABLE_NAME, ...fields } of source) {
                        result[TABLE_NAME] = result[TABLE_NAME] || [];
                        result[TABLE_NAME].push({ ...fields });
}`

Comment: TIL, thanks! https://medium.com/@mautayro/es6-variable-declaration-for-loops-why-const-works-in-a-for-in-loop-but-not-in-a-normal-a200cc5467c2

Answer (score 23):

```js
var cars = [{
  make: 'audi',
  model: 'r8',
  year: '2012'
}, {
  make: 'audi',
  model: 'rs5',
  year: '2013'
}, {
  make: 'ford',
  model: 'mustang',
  year: '2012'
}, {
  make: 'ford',
  model: 'fusion',
  year: '2015'
}, {
  make: 'kia',
  model: 'optima',
  year: '2012'
}].reduce((r, car) => {

  const {
    model,
    year,
    make
  } = car;

  r[make] = [...r[make] || [], {
    model,
    year
  }];

  return r;
}, {});

console.log(cars);
```

Comment: need urgent help how to store above like [ {  {"audi": [ { "model": "r8", "year": "2012" }] },{  {"ford": [ { "model": "r9", "year": "2021" }] } ...] each in object

Answer (score 12):

I'd leave `REAL GROUP BY` for JS Arrays example exactly the same this task [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52797477/4882514)

```js
const inputArray = [ 
    { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 1", Value: "5" },
    { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 2", Value: "10" },
    { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 1", Value: "15" },
    { Phase: "Phase 1", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 2", Value: "20" },
    { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 1", Value: "25" },
    { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 1", Task: "Task 2", Value: "30" },
    { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 1", Value: "35" },
    { Phase: "Phase 2", Step: "Step 2", Task: "Task 2", Value: "40" }
];

var outObject = inputArray.reduce(function(a, e) {
  // GROUP BY estimated key (estKey), well, may be a just plain key
  // a -- Accumulator result object
  // e -- sequentally checked Element, the Element that is tested just at this itaration

  // new grouping name may be calculated, but must be based on real value of real field
  let estKey = (e['Phase']); 

  (a[estKey] ? a[estKey] : (a[estKey] = null || [])).push(e);
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(outObject);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can try to modify the object inside the function called per iteration by _.groupBy func. 
Notice that the source array change his elements!

```
var res = _.groupBy(cars,(car)=>{
    const makeValue=car.make;
    delete car.make;
    return makeValue;
})
console.log(res);
console.log(cars);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: It looks like the best answer to me since you go through the array only once to get the desired result. There's no need to use another function to remove the `make` property, and it is more readable as well.

Answer (score 9):

**Just simple forEach loop will work here without any library**

```js
var cars = [
{
    'make': 'audi',
    'model': 'r8',
    'year': '2012'
}, {
    'make': 'audi',
    'model': 'rs5',
    'year': '2013'
}, {
    'make': 'ford',
    'model': 'mustang',
    'year': '2012'
}, {
    'make': 'ford',
    'model': 'fusion',
    'year': '2015'
}, {
    'make': 'kia',
    'model': 'optima',
    'year': '2012'
},
];
let ObjMap ={};

  cars.forEach(element => {
    var makeKey = element.make;
     if(!ObjMap[makeKey]) {
       ObjMap[makeKey] = [];
     }

    ObjMap[makeKey].push({
      model: element.model,
      year: element.year
    });
   });
   console.log(ObjMap);
```

Answer (score 6):

**[A proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-grouping) that adds [`Object.groupBy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy) and [`Map.groupBy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/groupBy) has reached Stage 4!**

It has already been implemented on most major browsers (see [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_object_groupby)) and so you are able to do this:

```js
const cars = [
  { make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' },
  { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' },
  { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' },
  { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }
];

const grouped = Object.groupBy(cars, item => item.make);
console.log(grouped);
```

which will output:

```js
{
  audi: [
    { make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' },
    { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' }
  ],
  ford: [
    { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' },
    { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' }
  ],
  kia: [
    { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }
  ]
}
```

You can also use [this core-js polyfill](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#array-grouping):

```js
const cars = [
  { make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' },
  { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' },
  { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' },
  { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' },
  { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }
];

const grouped = Object.groupBy(cars, item => item.make);
//console.log(grouped);

// Optional: remove the "make" property from resulting object
const entriesUpdated = Object
  .entries(grouped)
  .map(([key, value]) => [
    key,
    value.map(({make, ...rest}) => rest)
  ]);
const noMake = Object.fromEntries(entriesUpdated);
console.log(noMake);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js-bundle@3.31.1/minified.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

For cases where key can be null and we want to group them as *others*

```
var cars = [{'make':'audi','model':'r8','year':'2012'},{'make':'audi','model':'rs5','year':'2013'},{'make':'ford','model':'mustang','year':'2012'},{'make':'ford','model':'fusion','year':'2015'},{'make':'kia','model':'optima','year':'2012'},
            {'make':'kia','model':'optima','year':'2033'},
            {'make':null,'model':'zen','year':'2012'},
            {'make':null,'model':'blue','year':'2017'},

           ];


 result = cars.reduce(function (r, a) {
        key = a.make || 'others';
        r[key] = r[key] || [];
        r[key].push(a);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
```

Answer (score 5):

Another one solution:

```js
var cars = [
    {'make': 'audi','model': 'r8','year': '2012'}, {'make': 'audi','model': 'rs5','year': '2013'}, 
    {'make': 'ford','model': 'mustang','year': '2012'}, {'make': 'ford','model': 'fusion','year': '2015'}, 
    {'make': 'kia','model': 'optima','year': '2012'},
];


const reducedCars = cars.reduce((acc, { make, model, year }) => (
    { 
      ...acc, 
      [make]: acc[make] ? [ ...acc[make], { model, year }] : [ { model, year } ],
    }
 ), {});

console.log(reducedCars);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function groupBy(data, property) {
  return data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const key = obj[property];
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = [];
    }
    acc[key].push(obj);
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
groupBy(people, 'age');
```

Answer (score 4):

Agree that unless you use these  often there is no need for an external library. Although similar solutions are available, I see that some of them are tricky to follow [here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/wattry/de36aa0fdecbab93adbaf4ff7818ef94) that has a solution with comments if you're trying to understand what is happening.

```js
const cars = [{
  'make': 'audi',
  'model': 'r8',
  'year': '2012'
}, {
  'make': 'audi',
  'model': 'rs5',
  'year': '2013'
}, {
  'make': 'ford',
  'model': 'mustang',
  'year': '2012'
}, {
  'make': 'ford',
  'model': 'fusion',
  'year': '2015'
}, {
  'make': 'kia',
  'model': 'optima',
  'year': '2012'
}, ];

/**
 * Groups an array of objects by a key an returns an object or array grouped by provided key.
 * @param array - array to group objects by key.
 * @param key - key to group array objects by.
 * @param removeKey  - remove the key and it's value from the resulting object.
 * @param outputType - type of structure the output should be contained in.
 */
const groupBy = (
  inputArray,
  key,
  removeKey = false,
  outputType = {},
) => {
  return inputArray.reduce(
    (previous, current) => {
      // Get the current value that matches the input key and remove the key value for it.
      const {
        [key]: keyValue
      } = current;
      // remove the key if option is set
      removeKey && keyValue && delete current[key];
      // If there is already an array for the user provided key use it else default to an empty array.
      const {
        [keyValue]: reducedValue = []
      } = previous;

      // Create a new object and return that merges the previous with the current object
      return Object.assign(previous, {
        [keyValue]: reducedValue.concat(current)
      });
    },
    // Replace the object here to an array to change output object to an array
    outputType,
  );
};

console.log(groupBy(cars, 'make', true))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also make use of [**`array#forEach()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method like this:

```js
const cars = [{ make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' }, { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }];

let newcars = {}

cars.forEach(car => {
  newcars[car.make] ? // check if that array exists or not in newcars object
    newcars[car.make].push({model: car.model, year: car.year})  // just push
   : (newcars[car.make] = [], newcars[car.make].push({model: car.model, year: car.year})) // create a new array and push
})

console.log(newcars);
```

Answer (score 3):

Prototype version using ES6 as well.
Basically this uses the reduce function to pass in an accumulator and current item, which then uses this to build your "grouped" arrays based on the passed in key. the inner part of the reduce may look complicated but essentially it is testing to see if the key of the passed in object exists and if it doesn't then create an empty array and append the current item to that newly created array otherwise using the spread operator pass in all the objects of the current key array and append current item. Hope this helps someone!.

```
Array.prototype.groupBy = function(k) {
  return this.reduce((acc, item) => ((acc[item[k]] = [...(acc[item[k]] || []), item]), acc),{});
};

const projs = [
  {
    project: "A",
    timeTake: 2,
    desc: "this is a description"
  },
  {
    project: "B",
    timeTake: 4,
    desc: "this is a description"
  },
  {
    project: "A",
    timeTake: 12,
    desc: "this is a description"
  },
  {
    project: "B",
    timeTake: 45,
    desc: "this is a description"
  }
];

console.log(projs.groupBy("project"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I liked @metakunfu answer, but it doesn't provide the expected output exactly.
Here's an updated that get rid of "make" in the final JSON payload.

```
var cars = [
    {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'r8',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'rs5',
        'year': '2013'
    }, {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'mustang',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'fusion',
        'year': '2015'
    }, {
        'make': 'kia',
        'model': 'optima',
        'year': '2012'
    },
];

result = cars.reduce((h, car) => Object.assign(h, { [car.make]:( h[car.make] || [] ).concat({model: car.model, year: car.year}) }), {})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

**Output:**

```
{  
   "audi":[  
      {  
         "model":"r8",
         "year":"2012"
      },
      {  
         "model":"rs5",
         "year":"2013"
      }
   ],
   "ford":[  
      {  
         "model":"mustang",
         "year":"2012"
      },
      {  
         "model":"fusion",
         "year":"2015"
      }
   ],
   "kia":[  
      {  
         "model":"optima",
         "year":"2012"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const reGroup = (list, key) => {
    const newGroup = {};
    list.forEach(item => {
        const newItem = Object.assign({}, item);
        delete newItem[key];
        newGroup[item[key]] = newGroup[item[key]] || [];
        newGroup[item[key]].push(newItem);
    });
    return newGroup;
};
```

```
const animals = [
  {
    type: 'dog',
    breed: 'puddle'
  },
  {
    type: 'dog',
    breed: 'labradoodle'
  },
  {
    type: 'cat',
    breed: 'siamese'
  },
  {
    type: 'dog',
    breed: 'french bulldog'
  },
  {
    type: 'cat',
    breed: 'mud'
  }
];
console.log(reGroup(animals, 'type'));
```

```
const cars = [
  {
      'make': 'audi',
      'model': 'r8',
      'year': '2012'
  }, {
      'make': 'audi',
      'model': 'rs5',
      'year': '2013'
  }, {
      'make': 'ford',
      'model': 'mustang',
      'year': '2012'
  }, {
      'make': 'ford',
      'model': 'fusion',
      'year': '2015'
  }, {
      'make': 'kia',
      'model': 'optima',
      'year': '2012'
  },
];

console.log(reGroup(cars, 'make'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Grouped Array of Object in typescript with this:

```
groupBy (list: any[], key: string): Map<string, Array<any>> {
    let map = new Map();
    list.map(val=> {
        if(!map.has(val[key])){
            map.set(val[key],list.filter(data => data[key] == val[key]));
        }
    });
    return map;
});
```

Comment: This looks inefficient as you do a search for each key. The search has most likely a complexity of O(n).

Comment: With Typescript you already have groupBy method. You can use by `your_array.groupBy(...)`

Answer (score 1):

I love to write it with no dependency/complexity just pure simple js.

```js
const mp = {}
const cars = [
  {
    model: 'Imaginary space craft SpaceX model',
    year: '2025'
  },
  {
    make: 'audi',
    model: 'r8',
    year: '2012'
  },
  {
    make: 'audi',
    model: 'rs5',
    year: '2013'
  },
  {
    make: 'ford',
    model: 'mustang',
    year: '2012'
  },
  {
    make: 'ford',
    model: 'fusion',
    year: '2015'
  },
  {
    make: 'kia',
    model: 'optima',
    year: '2012'
  }
]

cars.forEach(c => {
  if (!c.make) return // exit (maybe add them to a "no_make" category)

  if (!mp[c.make]) mp[c.make] = [{ model: c.model, year: c.year }]
  else mp[c.make].push({ model: c.model, year: c.year })
})

console.log(mp)
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a benchmark to test the performance of each solution that don't use external libraries.

[JSBen.ch](https://jsben.ch/ZQyZo)

The `reduce()` option, posted by @Nina Scholz seems to be the optimal one.

Answer (score 1):

```
letfinaldata=[]

let data =[{id:1,name:"meet"},{id:2,name:"raj"},{id:1,name:"hari"},{id:3,name:"hari"},{id:2,name:"ram"}]

data = data.map((item)=> 
{
    return {...item,
        name: [item.name]
    }
}) // Converting the name key from string to array


let temp = [];

for(let i =0 ;i<data.length;i++)
{
    const index = temp.indexOf(data[i].id) // Checking if the object id is already present
    if(index>=0)
    {
        letfinaldata[index].name = [...letfinaldata[index].name,...data[i].name] // If present then append the name to the name of that object
    }
    else{
        temp.push(data[i].id); // Push the checked object id
        letfinaldata.push({...data[i]}) // Push the object
    }
}

console.log(letfinaldata)
```

**Output**

```
[ { id: 1, name: [ 'meet', 'hari' ] },
  { id: 2, name: [ 'raj', 'ram' ] },
  { id: 3, name: [ 'hari' ] } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

**2023**

[Object.groupBy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy) has arrived in native JavaScript -

```js
const cars = [
    {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'r8',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'rs5',
        'year': '2013'
    }, {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'mustang',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'fusion',
        'year': '2015'
    }, {
        'make': 'kia',
        'model': 'optima',
        'year': '2012'
    },
];

console.log(Object.groupBy(
  cars,
  car => car.make,
))
```

In [supported browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=Object.groupBy), as of October 2023 -

```json
{
  "audi": [
    {
      "make": "audi",
      "model": "r8",
      "year": "2012"
    },
    {
      "make": "audi",
      "model": "rs5",
      "year": "2013"
    }
  ],
  "ford": [
    {
      "make": "ford",
      "model": "mustang",
      "year": "2012"
    },
    {
      "make": "ford",
      "model": "fusion",
      "year": "2015"
    }
  ],
  "kia": [
    {
      "make": "kia",
      "model": "optima",
      "year": "2012"
    }
  ]
}
```

| Browser | Version |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chrome | 117 | ✅ |
| Edge | 117 | ✅ |
| Firefox | 119 | ✅ |
| Opera | 103 | ✅ |
| Safari | TP | ⚠️ |

Answer (score 0):

With lodash/fp you can create a function with `_.flow()` that 1st groups by a key, and then map each group, and omits a key from each item:

```js
const { flow, groupBy, mapValues, map, omit } = _;

const groupAndOmitBy = key => flow(
  groupBy(key),
  mapValues(map(omit(key)))
);

const cars = [{ make: 'audi', model: 'r8', year: '2012' }, { make: 'audi', model: 'rs5', year: '2013' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'mustang', year: '2012' }, { make: 'ford', model: 'fusion', year: '2015' }, { make: 'kia', model: 'optima', year: '2012' }];

const groupAndOmitMake = groupAndOmitBy('make');

const result = groupAndOmitMake(cars);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51563349/2842348) by @Jonas_Wilms if you do not want to type in all your fields:

```
    var result = {};

    for ( let { first_field, ...fields } of your_data ) 
    { 
       result[first_field] = result[first_field] || [];
       result[first_field].push({ ...fields }); 
    }
```

I didn't make any benchmark but I believe using a for loop would be more efficient than anything suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top) as well.

Comment: A for...of loop is the least efficient. Use a for(i...) for a forEach loop

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution inspired from Collectors.groupingBy() in Java:

```js
function groupingBy(list, keyMapper) {
  return list.reduce((accummalatorMap, currentValue) => {
    const key = keyMapper(currentValue);
    if(!accummalatorMap.has(key)) {
      accummalatorMap.set(key, [currentValue]);
    } else {
      accummalatorMap.set(key, accummalatorMap.get(key).push(currentValue));
    }
    return accummalatorMap;
  }, new Map());
}
```

This will give a Map object.

```js
// Usage

const carMakers = groupingBy(cars, car => car.make);
```

Answer (score -1):

While it isn't in the interest of answering your question with the most optimal or efficient code, I thought this a fun oportunity to turn this into a [Code Golf](https://code.golf/) exercise.

This is a slightly altered version of [@metakungfus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47385953/1720829), main difference being that it omits the original key from the resulting objects since it's no longer needed on the object itself in some cases since it's now available in the parent object.

Additionally, it heavily utilizes object, parameter and array expansion along with the [`reduce JavaScript function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const groupBy=(_k, a)=>a.reduce((r,{[_k]:k,...p})=>({...r,...{[k]: (r[k]?[...r[k],{...p}]:[{...p}])}}),{});
```

Considering your original input object:

```js
const cars = [
    {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'r8',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'rs5',
        'year': '2013'
    }, {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'mustang',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'fusion',
        'year': '2015'
    }, {
        'make': 'kia',
        'model': 'optima',
        'year': '2012'
    },
];
```

```js
console.log(groupBy('make', cars));
```

Would result in:

```js
{
  audi: [
    { model: 'r8', year: '2012' },
    { model: 'rs5', year: '2013' }
  ],
  ford: [
    { model: 'mustang', year: '2012' },
    { model: 'fusion', year: '2015' }
  ],
  kia: [
    { model: 'optima', year: '2012' }
  ]
}
```

Comment: very unreadable code

Answer (score -1):

```js
const groupBy = (array, callback) => {
  const groups = {};
  
  array.forEach((element) => {
    const groupName = callback(element);
    if (groupName in groups) {
      groups[groupName].push(element);
    } else {
      groups[groupName] = [element];
    }
  });
  
  return groups;
};
```

or for fancy pants:

```js
(() => {
  Array.prototype.groupBy = function (callback) {
    const groups = {};
    this.forEach((element, ...args) => {
      const groupName = callback(element, ...args);
      if (groupName in groups) {
        groups[groupName].push(element);
      } else {
        groups[groupName] = [element];
      }
    });

    return groups;
  };
})();

const res = [{ name: 1 }, { name: 1 }, { name: 0 }].groupBy(({ name }) => name);

// const res = {
//   0: [{name: 0}],
//   1: [{name: 1}, {name: 1}]
// }
```

This is a polyfill for the [MDN Array.groupBy function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/groupBy#browser_compatibility).

Answer (score -1):

This is a generic function which will return Array groupBy its own key.

```js
const getSectionListGroupedByKey = < T > (
  property: keyof T,
  List: Array < T >
): Array < {
  title: T[keyof T];data: Array < T >
} > => {
  const sectionList: Array < {
    title: T[keyof T];data: Array < T >
  } > = [];

  if (!property || !List ? .[0] ? .[property]) {
    return [];
  }

  const groupedTxnListMap: Map < T[keyof T], Array < T >> = List.reduce((acc, cv) => {
    const keyValue: T[keyof T] = cv[property];

    if (acc.has(keyValue)) {
      acc.get(keyValue) ? .push(cv);
    } else {
      acc.set(keyValue, [cv]);
    }

    return acc;
  }, new Map < T[keyof T], Array < T >> ());

  groupedTxnListMap.forEach((value, key) => {
    sectionList.push({
      title: key,
      data: value
    });
  });

  return sectionList;
};


// Example
const cars = [{
  'make': 'audi',
  'model': 'r8',
  'year': '2012'
}, {
  'make': 'audi',
  'model': 'rs5',
  'year': '2013'
}, {
  'make': 'ford',
  'model': 'mustang',
  'year': '2012'
}, {
  'make': 'ford',
  'model': 'fusion',
  'year': '2015'
}, {
  'make': 'kia',
  'model': 'optima',
  'year': '2012'
}, ];

const result = getSectionListGroupedByKey('make', cars);
console.log('result: ', result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```js
groupBy= (a,f) => a.reduce( (x,c) => (x[f(c)]??=[]).push(c)&&x, {} )
```

```js
const cars = [
    {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'r8',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'audi',
        'model': 'rs5',
        'year': '2013'
    }, {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'mustang',
        'year': '2012'
    }, {
        'make': 'ford',
        'model': 'fusion',
        'year': '2015'
    }, {
        'make': 'kia',
        'model': 'optima',
        'year': '2012'
    },
];

const groupBy= (a,f) => a.reduce( (x,c) => (x[f(c)]??=[]).push(c)&&x, {} )

console.log('gr', groupBy(cars, o=>o.make));
```

This answer is inspired by cdiggins [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48981669/860099) and Endless [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-can-i-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key/47385953#comment129992972_48981669) (without key remove in final objects). The improvement is that we have same small size but function interface `groupBy(a,f)` not contains additional redundant variables. To get array of grouped arrays you can use `Object.values(groupBy(cars, o=>o.make))`

Answer (score -2):

Here is another solution to it. As requested.

> I want to make a new array of car objects that's grouped by make:

```
function groupBy() {
  const key = 'make';
  return cars.reduce((acc, x) => ({
    ...acc,
    [x[key]]: (!acc[x[key]]) ? [{
      model: x.model,
      year: x.year
    }] : [...acc[x[key]], {
      model: x.model,
      year: x.year
    }]
  }), {})
}
```

Output:

```
console.log('Grouped by make key:',groupBy())
```